# How to format a number to display with 2 digits IN JAVAFX SQL PROJECT

Tags: java, javafx, h2

I'd like to always show a numbers in my tableView with 2 dignits. Right know my values are showing like "150.0", I want them to show as a 150.00 etc. I know that is a "String.format("%02d", myNumber)", but I don't know how to implement this function in my table. I was thinking about executeQuery "select cast(price to decimal(10,2) from data" but I don't know how to do it, how to make my getDataList class convert a price column to 2 dignits. In sql my price column is decimal(6,2) type, but in tableview they are changing. What do you think about it?

Here is my code:

```
    private ObservableList<Data> getDataList() {
        ObservableList<Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        DBConnection DBConnection = new DBConnection();
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                dataList.add(new Data(
                        result.getInt("id"),
                        result.getString("name"),
                        result.getString("category"),
                        result.getFloat("price"),
                        result.getString("date"))
                );
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataList;
    }
    private void showData() {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        categoryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("category"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));

        searchData();

        dateColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
        table.getSortOrder().add(dateColumn);
        table.sort();
    }
    private void searchData() {
        FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
        search.textProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {
                if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else return String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase);
            });
            setTotal();
        });
        SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
        table.setItems(sortedData);
        setTotal();
    }
    private void setTotal() {
        float totalAmount = 0;
        totalAmount = table.getItems().stream().map(
                Data::getPrice).reduce(totalAmount, Float::sum);
        total.setText("Total: "+totalAmount);
    }
}
```

How to make it works in my showData() method? How can I implement 2 dignits decimal in my setCellValueFactory?

Comment: I was trying with setMinimumFractionDignits(2) in initialize method but it didn't work